# how to fetch data from this api using 'POST' method in javascript

Tags: javascript, fetch

url---http://eign-backend.herokuapp.com/property/get-property/17/

Do i have to write complete url like till "/17/" or what!

```
const response=await fetch('url',{
      method:'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(
        {
         //what should I write here
        }
      ),
      headers:{
        headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
      }
    })
    const data=await response.json();
    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: You write the URL where it says URL. We've no idea what you should put in the body as we know nothing about the API.

Comment: It depends but `http://eign-backend.herokuapp.com/property/get-property/17/` is most likely to work. i.e. `await fetch('http://eign-backend.herokuapp.com/property/get-property/17/', {`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

try this

```
async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
  
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
    body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  });
  return response.json(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
}

postData('https://example.com/answer', { answer: 42 })
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data); // JSON data parsed by `data.json()` call
  });
```

Comment: Why? That is the wrong URL, (presumably) the wrong body, and a whole lot of pointless boilerplate (which I've seen somewhere before so this stinks of plagiarization) .

Answer (score 0):

First argument in fetch is the *actual* url

```
 const response=await fetch('http://eign-backend.herokuapp.com/property/get-property/17/',{
          method:'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(
            {
             //what should I write here => write whatever you want to send in this post request's body
            }
          ),
          headers:{
            headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
          }
        })
 const data=await response.json();
 console.log(data);
```

Consider reading some [documentation](https://javascript.info/fetch) first

Answer (score -1):

You can directly make a POST request on that URL. It's OK to send a POST request without a body and instead use query string parameters but then it should have been a get request instead of POST if there is no need for the body. But be careful if your parameters contain characters that are not HTTP valid you will have to encode them.

```
var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("http://eign-backend.herokuapp.com/property/get-property/17/", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

This is the fetch call that I have used.